# How to define a NFS root in a discrete directory tree?

Tags: nfs

I would like to setup a NFS-server for multiple docker containers and I found documentation on the [archlinux-wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NFS).
I thought of this project as an useful example to get to know NFS-configuration and it's security details.

I am not sure what the following sentence means and how to do it.

> A good security practice is to define a NFS root in a discrete directory tree which will keep users limited to that mount point.

Does that just mean to create a specific directory for the shared data and not have it accross multiple users home directory?

server OS: centos7 or 8

Comment: I am having trouble matching concrete steps in the example to the description: mkdir -p /srv/nfs/music /mnt/music creates two directories + /srv/nfs if it does not exist. So I can assume that /srv/nfs is the nfs root directory, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what's going on here and why the Arch wiki is confusing.

Ancient versions of NFS from back in the 1990s (version 3 and previous) could simply export arbitrary directories which were located anywhere in the filesystem. This changed with NFSv4, which requires all exported directories to be subdirectories of a top-level "root" export which is defined by the system administrator and carries the export option `fsid=0` to distinguish it as the root. There is no predefined root; the admin makes an explicit choice to define the root.

Thus if you define `/srv/nfs` as the root, all other NFSv4 exports must be subdirectories of that directory.

However, it is likely that the directory you want to export is not actually under `/srv/nfs`. For example you may want to export `/var/lib/docker/volumes`. To do this, instead of moving the files around which might break things that depend on them being in their original location, you can create a bind mount so that the files remain in their original place in the filesystem but are also visible under the bind-mounted path.

```
mkdir /srv/nfs/volumes
mount --bind /var/lib/docker/volumes /srv/nfs/volumes
```

Now the files are available in both places in the filesystem tree, and because of that, NFSv4 can export them.

The only bit I am still confused about is why the Arch wiki calls it a "good security practice" when it is just how NFSv4 works.